# Safari does not find CSS-file in folder above for HTML-subpage

Tags: html, css, path, safari

when I am opening an html-file (let's call it subpage.html) which is in a subfolder with respect to the main.css-file of my website, Safari is not able to read the main.css-file for this subpage (the subpage is displayed without any css-styling).

I referred to the css-file by putting the following into the head of the subpage.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css">
```

I opened the subpage.html in Google Chrome, and Google Chrome was able to read the css-file without any issues, so the path to the file should be okay.

And also Safari is able to read the css-file for the subpage as long as I open the index.html first and navigate via links to the subpage. When I do it like this, the subpage has the intended css-styling. But after clicking on Safari's refresh button or when opening the subpage individually, the style is missing again. It is absolutely weird.

I found this problem on two different Mac computers!

I found out that this problem disappears when I activate "CSS content visibility" in the developer tools (feature flags) of Safari, which is deactivated by default.

Any suggestions what the problem might be? The webpage is not online so far. Do you think a webpage visitor will have problems to open the subpage with the intended css-styling (I assume the standard visitor won't activate "CSS content visibility" before visiting my webpage ;) ?

Comment: Where is your main.css in a subfolder too?

Comment: the main.css is in my "root" folder

Comment: That’s really wired, you should be using a local server anyway, on the mac you can simply use `python3 -m http.server` in the ternimal

Comment: I am using brackets... my problem only appears when clicking on the subpage.html file in the finder